# Django 404.html for mobile site

Tags: django

My django site is having web & mobile versions. I have enabled debug setting false which returns templates 404.html whenever the requested page is not found. I would like to modify the view function to return 2 different 404 html pages like 404.html/404mobile.html based on platform.

Detecting user browser through JavaScript in 404.html page did not help as my 404.html page has header and footer extends from base html file.

Modifying views will solve this? If so where is the debug setting class file residing in Django package?

Comment: have look into https://pypi.python.org/pypi/user-agents

Comment: @rajasimon, thanks buddy, my question is not to identify user agents but how to handle two different 404 pages

Comment: Check if the browser is a mobile device based on the user agent and then serve the correct view accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.views.static import * 
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.defaults import handler404
from app.views import error

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'app.views.home', name='home'),
)

handler404 = error.error_handler
```

overriding handler404 method resolves this issue

Comment: btw all django handler class resides in django.views.defaults

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function using user_agent ..

```
from user_agents import parse

def idfy(request):
    user_agent = parse(ua_string)
    if user_agent.is_mobile:
        return HttpResponse('I m n mobile')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('I m n pc')
```

Comment: question is where to add this function!

Comment: in `views.py`. change the function name whatever you want .